# Understanding `Kind` of `Random`

Tags: haskell

`Maybe`, which I understand to be a `type constructor`, has kind `* -> *`. As I understand, it needs a type in order to produce a type.

```
ghci> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
ghci> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

However, what does the following output mean?

```
ghci> :k Random
Random :: * -> Constraint
```

Comment: See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a handful of kinds in Haskell.  A concrete type has kind `*`, this means that it is fully applied, so types like `Int`, `[String]`, `IO (Maybe Int)`.  Then there are kinds that take the form `* -> k`, where `k` is a kind variable.  These are just like functions in Haskell that take 1 or more arguments, except `*` *has* to be a concrete type, it isn't variable.  Examples would be

```
> :kind Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
> :kind Either
Either :: * -> * -> *
> data Foo a b c d e = Foo
> :kind Foo
Foo :: * -> * -> * -> * -> * -> *
```

Then there is the kind `Constraint`, which is constructed with one or more<sup>1</sup> other kinds:

```
> :kind Num
Num :: * -> Constraint
> :kind Show
Show :: * -> Constraint
> import Control.Monad.State
> :kind MonadState
MonadState :: * -> (* -> *) -> Constriant
```

The last one is a bit more complex, but think of it like a higher order function, where `(* -> *)` means that the second argument must be a type constructor that has one type argument left.

`Random` is just a simple typeclass, so it takes a fully applied type and produces a `Constraint`.

There is also the primitive kind `#`, values of types that are primitive and baked in to GHC, they even require a language extension just to parse their names:

```
> import GHC.Prim
> :set -XMagicHash
> :i Int#
data Int#
> :k Int#
Int# :: #
```

Most Haskell programmers won't ever need to use these, but they're available if you need to do low level programming for the GHC API.

With a couple extensions, you can even make kinds yourself

```
> :set -XDataKinds
> :set -XKindSignatures
> :set -XGADTs
> -- Multiline input in GHCi
> :set +m
> data FlagType = Flag1 | Flag2 deriving (Show)
> data Foo :: FlagType -> * -> *
|     F1 :: Int -> Foo 'Flag1 Int
|     F2 :: String -> Foo 'Flag2 String
|
> :t F1 1
F1 1 :: Foo 'Flag1 Int
> :t F2 "foo"
F2 "foo" :: Foo 'Flag2 String
```

Kinds give us a form of type level programming, there are lots of tricks that can be done with them to build nice APIs.

<sup>1.</sup> [Not necessarily true](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-10-nullary-type-classes.html)